# the parameter 'body' is not defined

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
Compiler message:
lib/main.dart:12:11: Error: No named parameter with the name 'body'.
          body: Image(
          ^^^^
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//main fuction is the starting point for all our apps.
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[150],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('I Am Rich'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
          body: Image(
            image:
                NetworkImage('https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `body` is a parameter of`Scaffold`, not `AppBar`

```
     Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[150],
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('I Am Rich'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,

            ),
            body: Image(
                image:
                    NetworkImage('https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg'),
              ),
          ),
```

More info here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html

Comment: you are welcome, don't forget to mark this answer as solved